# Wifi keeps dropping connection

Tags: wireless, connection, intel-wireless, x230

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Thinkpad X230 with Intel Centrino Advended-N 6205 wifi. On my home network everything is fine, but at work the connection keeps dropping after a minute of being connected. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Azalus

Comment: Give us some basic indicators, like signal strength at home and at work.

Comment: Signal strength isn't an issue as I am right by the router at both places.

Answer (score 0):

If your work uses PEAP and whatnot for wifi authentication there are several issues with it on ubuntu and other distros.  I have had moderate success by connecting to a hidden network with the corporate network's name rather than clicking on it and connecting to it.  I am still prompted for a password every time I get to work though.  You can troubleshoot most of these issues by editing the connection file in :

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if it's not PEAP? (I don't know that it isn't...) What then? What else can I try?

Comment: you could still look at the configuration file inside the system-connections folder and see if anything else looks strange.  If your company uses Active Directory or some over form of SSO application there is a good chance that it is WPA Enterprise (PEAP, EAP, ect) type encryption.

If it's not, you will have to look at your signal strength, it is possible that there is a "louder talker" near your office's access point(s)